# Play Framework: PersistenceException: The type is not a registered entity? (Ebean)

Tags: java, persistence, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm following the Play Framework 2.0 tutorial for Java and get this error when trying to save an ebean Model (`task.save()`).

> [PersistenceException: The type [class models.Task] is not a
>   registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to
>   use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a
>   Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or
>   check ServerConfig.addJar().]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check these 3 points :

- Your model is annotated with `@Entity` (javax.persistence.Entity)
- Your model extends `Model` (play.db.ebean.Model)
- [Ebean is enable](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean) in your application.conf `ebean.default="models.*"` (if your classes are in the models package)

Comment: I got the same problem, and my error was not extends Model. Thank you very much.