# Play Framework: 2.0.2 PersistenceException:Cannot register class in Ebean server

Tags: playframework, persistence, playframework-2.0, ebean

First of all, this question may seem much alike:
[Play Framework: PersistenceException: The type is not a registered entity? (Ebean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824190/play-framework-persistenceexception-the-type-is-not-a-registered-entity-ebea) but it's not...

I'm trying to save an entity but it doesn't even render the template, after I restart Play it just gives the error in the subject.
Of course, the app compiles.

I've done all the steps to use EBean with Play:

- annotated model with `@Entity` (javax.persistence.Entity)
- model extends Model (`play.db.ebean.Model`)
- Ebean is enable in my `application.conf` `ebean.default="models.*"` (my classes are in the `models` package)

Any suggestions? Tests I can do? Things to check?
To be fair, stackoverflow is my last resort...

Thanks in advance,

Complete stack trace:

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error [Cannot register class [models.Producer] in Ebean server]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:71) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:258) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.java:119) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:71) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_02]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.7.0_02]
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:69) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourcePool.<init>(DataSourcePool.java:198) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceManager.getDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:210) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceGlobalManager.getDataSource(DataSourceGlobalManager.java:63) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultServerFactory.java:427) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.setDataSource(DefaultServerFactory.java:388) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:168) ~[ebean.jar:na]
```

Comment: get the same issue .. :\ this is driving me crazy

Comment: For me, it happens every single time the directory of the play project is changed. Somewhere somehow, it hard codes the directory where the play runs from in compiled code.

Answer (score 14):

I had exactly the same issue described in the first post. It is weird, in my case, just running

```
# play 

> clean
> compile
> run
```

the app started to work again

Comment: I updated Java to version 8 which led me to unknown constant errors. Updating SBT from 0.13.0 to 0.13.1 fixed that. After that I got this Ebean registration error which was fixed with the given commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Ebeans configurations, some association is not correct. Maybe you changed something in their application models and not recorded in Ebean.

Answer (score -1):

From the log, it seems that you have to set the Datasource user:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?
```

You can do that by editing pour conf/application.con file:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:DB_NAME"
db.default.user=sa        <-- HERE !!
db.default.password=""
db.default.logStatements=true
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but that wasn't it... My database was set in application.conf. I don't know what the problem was, when I started on a fresh application and took things slow (one thing at a time) it just worked. I'm frustrated by this moody behaviour of play...

Comment: For me, it was caused by `ebean.default="models.*"` line in config commented out, but in this question this key seems to be set correctly. Setting user and password for h2 is unnecessarry, tried without it — it works too.