# Play 2.3.8 + Hibernate 4.3.8 - Execution exception[[PersistenceException: The type [] is not a registered entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

Please help me in resolving below issue... 
this.save() is throwing error :

> The type [class model.db.bean.accounting.CustomerTable] is not a
>   registered entity?

but this bean is registered and data retrieval is working fine with same bean...

Issue is different from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824190/play-framework-persistenceexception-the-type-is-not-a-registered-entity-ebea)...

Error :

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: The type [class model.db.bean.accounting.CustomerTable] is not a registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

CustomerTable :

```
            package model.db.bean.accounting;

            import javax.persistence.Column;
            import javax.persistence.Entity;
            import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
            import javax.persistence.Id;
            import javax.persistence.Table;

            import play.db.ebean.Model;
            @Table(name = "accounting.customer")
            @Entity
            public class CustomerTable extends Model {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                private String customerId;
                private String accountId;
                private String accountUsername;

                public CustomerTable()
                {
                    super();
                }

                public CustomerTable create(controllers.beans.Customer cCustomers) {
                    this.customerId = cCustomers.getCustomerId();
                    this.accountId = cCustomers.getAccountId();
                    this.accountUsername =  cCustomers.getAccountUsername();
                    this.save();
                    return this;
                }

                @Id
                @GeneratedValue
                @Column(name="customer_id")
                public String getCustomerId() {
                    return customerId;
                }
                @Column(name="account_id")
                public String getAccountId() {
                    return accountId;
                }
                @Column(name="account_username")
                public String getAccountUsername() {
                    return accountUsername;
                }
                public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
                    this.customerId = customerId;
                }
                public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
                    this.accountId = accountId;
                }
                public void setAccountUsername(String accountUsername) {
                    this.accountUsername = accountUsername;
                }
            }
```

App config :

```
    ...                
    ebean.accounting="model.db.bean.accounting.*"
    ..
```

Comment: please share the entity `CustomerTable`

Comment: @ankur-singhal added customertable. thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved this issue!... I have to pass database name as parameter to "save" function ... like this...

```
public CustomerTable create(controllers.beans.Customer cCustomers) {
                    this.customerId = cCustomers.getCustomerId();
                    this.accountId = cCustomers.getAccountId();
                    this.accountUsername =  cCustomers.getAccountUsername();
                    //Pass schema name as parameter
                    this.save("accounting");
                    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your import to

```java
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
```

this issue will resolved.
Other thinking

In your App config :

```java
ebean.default = "models.db.ebean.*"
```